# do we need to escape the character '<'

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping

In C# ASP.NET, if we have the characters < or > in a string. Do we need to escape it like:

`string a = "\<test\>abcdef\</test\>"`

because this string will be send to an external method via webservices.
And in that method, it will be converted to a some kind of xml file.

```
contentHtml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>" + contentHtml;
content_ws.AddContent(contentHtml);
//AddContent() method is a external method (via webservices)
```

For example ô is now converted to Ã´. But i can't reach the code in de Web Service

Thx for help

Comment: Depends on what you plan to do with the string afterwards, but most likely no, you don't have to.

Comment: What will this string be used for? Can you show us the usage context?

Answer (score 7):

No you don't need to escape these characters. What stopped you from trying this out yourself?

**UPDATE**

Based on your further information I'd say it depends on what the Web Service is expecting. It's likely that the Web Service will encode incoming string data. Have you tried this? What are your current results?

Comment: what stopped you from telling us this in your question? Simply asking about putting these characters in a string tells us nothing about how you're going to use it. It'll be worth updating your question with this relevant information.

Comment: I have no idea how the Web Service Looks like and i can't ask it to anyone. For example: ô is converted to Ã´

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're doing? Why are you sending this to a web service? What happens next? What are you expecting?

Comment: We are working with a CMS system. and when we give this string to the external method `AddContent()`. then it will be added as content in the cms system. But the problem is, when we have é è or ô (or some other french character), that it doesn't converts it right.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. `<` and `>` needs no escaping. The only time you might need to escape `<` and `>` is when the string is represented as data inside of XML in which case `<` has to be `&lt;` and `>` has to be `&gt;`.

EDIT:

for `asp.net` you can use

```
string a = "<test>abcdef</test>";
string encodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(a);
```

Comment: @Ozkan In that case, there are multiple way to escape data see http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe no escape character is needed. Have a look on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) link

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the string is encoded in UTF-16(seems to be the one you are using) before sending!